# I couldn’t have correct date numbers which pointed to create date of my media files. (android)

Tags: android, file, date, format

Hello my stackoverflow friends. I am a initial android developer and sometimes something bothers me while programming! I have bellow method for get create date an audio or video file in my special job. 
Method is :

```
public static String getCrDate(File file)
   {
       long lastTime = file.lastModified();
         Date nowDate = new Date(lastTime);          
         String  createDate=nowDate.getMonth()+"/"+nowDate.getDate()+"/"
                                        +nowDate.getYear(); 
          return createDate;
   }
```

But I faced with an out put like this 0/17/114 instead of 1/17/2014 or 11/17/113 instead of 12/17/2013 . (format is month/day/year) .I couldn’t have correct date numbers which pointed to create date of my media files. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear) the method getYear returns the year minus 1900. the numbers of months is from 0 to 11 so you should make a plus 1 with the getMonth as well.

anyway I would suggest you to use the more reliable object Calendar:

```
public static String getCrDate(File file) {
long lastTime = file.lastModified();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(lastTime);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String  createDate = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;

return createDate;
```

Comment: thank u for java doc but using from Calendar couldnt help me. cuz this part is wrong completly . long lastTime = file.lastModified();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(lastTime);  getInstance method needs Local parameter not a long.please remove this part of your code or correct it.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. you are right: you have to call the method setTimeInMillis(lastTime) to set the time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

i change my code to this and solved my problem: according to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear) the method getYear returns the year minus 1900. the numbers of months is from 0 to 11 so you should make a plus 1 with the getMonth as well.

```
public static String getCrDate(File file)
   {
       long lastTime = file.lastModified();
         Date nowDate = new Date(lastTime);          
         String  createDate=(nowDate.getMonth()+1)"/"+nowDate.getDay()+"/"
                                        +(nowDate.getYear()+1900); 
          return createDate;
   }
```